# Integrate $\int_1^4xf''(x)dx$ given some known values

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Knowing $f(1) = 2, f(4)=7,f'(1) = 5,f'(4)=3$

Find
$\int_1^4xf''(x)dx$

It is obvious that if there was no $x$ the answer would be $f'(4) - f'(1)$ from the fundamental theorem of calculus. I'm not sure what I do with that $x$ though.Is it treated like a constant in this case? Do I need to use integration by parts or a u-substitution? If so I can't seem to find the correct substitution. I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious...

Comment: Definitely integration by parts :)

Comment: There are only two ways to integrate by parts that make sense. Have you tried both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use integration by parts.
$$\int_1^4xf''(x)\,dx=[xf'(x)]_1^4-\int_1^4f'(x)\,dx$$
$$=4f'(4)-f'(1)-f(4)+f(1)=4×3-5-7+2=2$$

Comment: Yup, pretty simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use integration by parts. Just integrate double prime and differentiate the x part, and you will have one more integral with one prime. Repeat the step and you should get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate, according to the given data, the integral

$\displaystyle \int_1^4 xf''(x) \; dx, \tag 1$

set

$u(x) = x, \; v(x) = f'(x); \tag 2$

then

$du = dx, \; dv = f''(x) dx; \tag 3$

now integrate by parts, using

$u \; dv = d(uv) - v \; du; \tag 4$

one finds

$\displaystyle \int_1^4 xf''(x) \; dx = ( x f'(x) \vert_1^4 - \int_1^4 f'(x) \; dx$
$= ( x f'(x) \vert_1^4 - (f(4) - f(1)) = (4(3) - 1(5)) - (7 - 2) = 2, \tag 5$

in agreement with the result of our colleague Parcly Taxel.